# Can i use two criteria for one If statement?

Tags: android, if-statement

For example there are two conditions, A and B.
Can i use between A or B in an IF? For example, IF(A or B)..
Is there the code to use either A or B condition for one if?
Thx.

Comment: do you want to continue if either of these conditions is true?

Comment: See [Conditional Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). Consider taking a break from code, drinking a cup of coffee, and following along with a tutorial. Questions about using such operators, if any questions remain, should *include* actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
if ( A || B )
{
    // Your code
}
```

In PHP, you can even use the OR word like so:

```
if ( A OR B )
{
    // Your code
}
```

You should read up on ||, |, and && operators or all the Tenary Operators to understand the effect better.

Comment: Check definition of ternary :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (A || B) {...} //OR
if (A && B) {...} //AND
```

The top is true if either A or B is true.
The bottom is true if A and B are true.